# Office 2007 addins: How to check that application is invoked using windows script?

Tags: c#, vsto

Hello guys

I have addin for Excel 2007 (developed using VSTO and C#) and lot of windows scripts for excel files management. The addin works fine when excel is opened by user (manualy), but some addin functionality should be disabled when excel is opened using windows script.

But I don't know how to check that application is opened using script..
It is a possible?
Thank you

Comment: I have found a solution. 
Property Application.Visible allow to check when application window is visible or not. Usually we don't show application window when application is opened using script.
So, I will use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. 
Property Application.Visible allow to check when application window is visible or not. 
Usually we don't show application window when application is opened using script. 
So, I will use it.